# Ruby on Rails I18n mailer subject translations in custom directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rails-i18n

I am using I18n gem for the translation. I have all my translation in a single file(en.yml, es.yml.. ).
But for emails, instead of translating each sentence in the email body I have a separate email view for each locale. So my email view files are structured like:

```
- views
    - user_mailer
      - notify_activation.en.html.erb
      - notify_activation.de.html.erb
      - notify_activation.es.html.erb
```

and my user mailer is like:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_activation user
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: t('mailer.user.activation.subject'))
  end
end
```

Now I want to place the mailer subject translation in a custom directory in the locale. So the locale structure will look like:

```
- config
  - locales
    - en
      - user_mailer.yml
      - *other mailers*.yml
    - de
      - user_mailer.yml
      - *other mailers*.yml
    - es
      - user_mailer.yml
      - *other mailers*.yml
    - devise.en.yml
    - en.yml
    - es.yml
    - de.yml
```

I searched for a solution but all in vain. I have come across solutions suggesting me to change the i18n.load_path in application.rb but that would change the path for all the translation and I only want to change load path for mailer subject. I was hoping for something like:

```
def load_path
  "#{I18n.locale}/#{self.class_name}"
end
```

in the application mailer.rb. Any solutions or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

P.S I am quite new to rails so don't mind being thorough.

Comment: What Rails version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Rails do it automatically (at least Rails 4+). Default *config/locales/en.yml* has the following comment:

> Files in the config/locales directory are used for internationalization
>   and are automatically loaded by Rails. If you want to use locales other
>   than English, add the necessary files in this directory.

So you can structure files in *config* dir as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Rails' I18n documentation: 
You can change the `load_path` in your `config/initializers/application.rb`

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'en', '*.yml')] 
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'es', '*.yml')] 
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', 'de', '*.yml')]
```